EventSubscription doesn't fire 1st time loads the immersive space in SwiftUI
Hi I have added a 3D object into Reality Composer pro. What I want to do is, to show names on multiple points of the same object Just like Apples Diorama example. Following is my code
var body: some View {
    @Bindable var viewModel = viewModel
    
    RealityView { content, _ in
        do {
            let immersiveContentEntity = try? await Entity(named: "Immersive", in:realityKitContentBundle)
            viewModel.rootentity = immersiveContentEntity
            content.add(immersiveContentEntity ?? Entity())
            //viewModel.updateScale()
            
            // Offset the scene so it doesn't appear underneath the user or conflict with the main window.
            //mmersiveContentEntity.position = SIMD3<Float>(0, 0, -2)
            
            subscriptions.append(content.subscribe(to: ComponentEvents.DidAdd.self, componentType: PointsOfInterestComponent.self, { event in
                createLearnMoreView(for: event.entity)
            }))
            
            
            //createLearnMoreView(for: immersiveContentEntity ?? Entity())
            
            } catch {
                print("Error in RealityView's make: \(error)")
            }
    } update: { content, attachments in
        
        print("UPDATE CALLED")
        viewModel.rootentity?.scene?.performQuery(Self.runtimeQuery).forEach { entity in
            
            guard let component = entity.components[PointsOfInterestRunTimeComponent.self],
            
                  let attachmentEntity = attachments.entity(for: component.attachmentTag) else { return }
            
            //guard attachmentEntity.parent == nil else {return}
            
            attachmentEntity.components.set(BillboardComponent())
            
            //entity.addChild(attachmentEntity)
            content.add(attachmentEntity)
            attachmentEntity.setPosition([0.0, 0.5, 0.0], relativeTo: entity)
        }
        
    } attachments: {
        ForEach(attachmentsProvider.sortedTagViewPairs, id: \.tag) { pair in
            Attachment(id: pair.tag) {
                pair.view
            }
        }
    }
}

I have added 2 transform entities into Reality Composer Pro like below and added custom components into it. Custom component only has 2 properties (name and description)
My ViewModel is like this
import Foundation
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent
import Observation

@Observable
final class ViewModel {
var rootentity: Entity? = nil
var showImmersiveContent: Bool = false

init(rootEntity: Entity? = nil, showImmersiveContent: Bool = false) {
    self.rootentity = rootEntity
    self.showImmersiveContent = showImmersiveContent
}  }

My Problem is I cannot see my attachments on the 3D view when I go into immersive view first time. When I close the immersive view and re-open it, then I can see it. It looks like this subscription doesn't fire when the immersive space loads 1st time.
subscriptions.append(content.subscribe(to: ComponentEvents.DidAdd.self, componentType: PointsOfInterestComponent.self, { event in
                createLearnMoreView(for: event.entity)
            }))

Does anybody know how to resolve this?
